# Запросы в MySQL через bat файл

Tags: mysql, sql, bat

На компе установлена MySQL.
Мне нужно через bat файл запустить ее и выполнить некоторые sql запросы, которые лежат в файле query.sql.
Подключаюсь к MySQL этой строкой:

> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -proot
>   Pause

Дальше нужно ввести запросы из файла query.sql или на крайний случай в самом батнике. Как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте в документации: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html

Comment: Как в документации не работает. Пробовал еще такой запрос                      "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" mysql -uroot -proot -i "D:\query.sql"  Но тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой работает

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" mysql -uroot -proot < D:\query.sql

Comment: Если вы установили переменные среды для mysql, тогда не нужно указывать полный путь до mysql.exe. Просто вызываете нужную команду прописывая 'mysql'.